# Scrolling gallery using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to build [this](http://www.pjohnson.com.au/) flash gallery using javascript. Can anyone point me towards something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at jQuery UI or jQuery Tools, they have many built in effects that might be able to do this.

Comment: jQuery Tools scrollable library looks like it might fit what you are looking for, it will take some good coding though.

Comment: I've built one slide show  with J query, but it was just a list of sliding images. Instead, I'm thinking to structure the gallery with 5 divs, so that when i click one of the outer divs the image scrolls over to the main image in the front.  does that sound like the best way to structure?

Comment: @Guided33: Exactly. You will need to figure out a way to control both the resizing, fading, and movement of the divs, plus populating them with new content and removing old content. Depending on how flexible you need it to be, you might just want to include some base effects and create the entire thing yourself.